# How to connect to Oracle DB from .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, web-config, connection-string

When I open SQL Command Line, I write `CONNECT username/password@[//]host[:port][/service_name]` and it connects me to the database just fine. However, I'm unable to connect from a .NET project using a connection string. I have tried many things such as `<add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=username/password@[//]host[:port][/service_name];" />` and `<add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="server=tcp:host;Initial Catalog=service_name; user id=username; password=password; Connection Timeout=180;" providerName="System.Data.OracleClient" />`, but nothing worked so far. Whenever I get to `sconn.Open();` in the following:

```
var CurrentConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection sconn = new SqlConnection(CurrentConnectionString);
sconn.Open();
```

I practically always get the following error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid)

How can I connect to the database properly?

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/

Comment: The server could be configured to not allow remote connections to.  That's a thing in all the main RDBMS servers, MSSQL, PostgreSQL, MySql, and I imagine Oracle to.

If it is not allowing remote connections then it will not be reachable even when your connection string is correct.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try following connection string

```
string con = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST = 000.00.0.00)(PORT = 0000)))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVICE_NAME = database)));User ID=User/Schema;Password=password;Unicode=True";
```

& then use this conection string as follow

```
using (OracleConnection objConn = new OracleConnection(con))
 {
   \\ code
 }
```

Comment: `OracleException: Could not allocate the Oracle environment.` when using this in a .NET Standard class library

Answer (score 3):

I highly recommend using the "Official Oracle ODP.NET, Managed Driver".

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/

Or the one for Entity framework:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework/

After installing via Visual Studio it opens a readme that I also recommend you read.

*Oracle provide massive amounts of documentation. This is where to start:*
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/whatsnew/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You use `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection` which is used to connect to a (Microsoft) **SQL Server**, it cannot be used for an Oracle connection.

You should use `System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection` or `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection`

Have a look at this answer to see other possibilities: 
[How to connect to Oracle 11 database from . net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34803106/how-to-connect-to-oracle-11-database-from-net/34805999#34805999)

Answer (score 0):

You can always use EF, and use create one `ADO.Net Entity Data Model`

[image]

And use the wizard to create and test the connection

[image]