# Connecting to ODBC Data Source in Visual Studio

Tags: windows, oracle, visual-studio, odbc

I had this working on my old 32-bit Windows 7 machine running VS 2010 but am having trouble on my new 64-bit Windows 7 machine running VS 2015.

All I want to do is add an Oracle ODBC connection to Visual Studio's Server Explorer. I get the following error:

[image: Visual Studio error with connecting to ODBC]

I have successfully configured and set up the 32-bit and 64-bit ODBC utilities with ODBC drivers, both pass the "test connection". Also I have set up Oracle SQL Developer to connect to the exact same source using the same credentials and I am able to read from the server in question. Here is the successful connection attempt in the ODBC utility:

[image: ODBC Success]

Comment: Which driver did you select in ODBC configuration? Looks like it is the driver from Oracle but in VS you selected the driver from Microsoft.

Comment: Oracle in OraClient11g_home1. I did try the "Microsoft ODBC for Oracle" also and got the same error message.

Comment: According to your screenshot you used ".NET Framework Data Provider for ODBC" which is the driver from Microsoft. Try the Oracle there.

Answer (score 1):

I removed the Oracle ODP.NET developer toolset for Visual Studio and now the connections are working. I find Oracle's software incredibly frustrating and hard to use.

Wernfried thank you for taking the time to help.

Comment: I prefer the manual way to connect to a database - I am really not a fan of such wizards. See examples here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34803106/how-to-connect-to-oracle-11-database-from-net/34805999#34805999