# visual studio 2015: could not load odp.net when dotConnect for Oracle installed

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-2015, odp.net, devart

I have ODP.NET installed using ODAC 32bit on a machine with `Devart dotConnect for Oracle` installed.

```
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/utilsoft-086879.html
```

Got the error when adding a `ADO.NET Entity Data Model`...\New Connection:

[image]

Click the 2nd time to get the same issue. However the 3rd time shows Devart screen:

[image]

ODP.NET is working fine on a machine without Devart dotConnect installed. Any idea please?

Comment: Can you debug your application? If not, try to establish connection manually like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34803106/how-to-connect-to-oracle-11-database-from-net/34805999#34805999

Comment: Whenever you get odd errors like this, you should first reinstall Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio. Have you tried that?