# arabic character not inserted properly(like ????) in oracle database?

Tags: asp.net, oracle

arabic character not insert to my oracle database with asp.net. I use below code to insert data to database but not inserted properly.
how to can i solve this problem?

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE SHAHR_POS SET SP_FLG=N'سلام'"
```

pls help me.

Comment: Which provider do you use? What is the database character set?

Comment: NLS_LANG : AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P1 and field of database as 'Nvarchar'

Comment: I did not ask for `NLS_LANG`. I asked "Which provider (or driver) do you use?" and "What is the database character set?" Check character set with `SELECT * 
    FROM V$NLS_PARAMETERS 
    WHERE PARAMETER LIKE '%CHARACTERSET';` For the provider/driver check the connectionString.

Comment: NLS_CHARACTERSET : WE8ISO8859P1 and NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET: AL16UTF16

Comment: data source=(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.20.*.*)(PORT = ****)))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVICE_NAME = ****)));user id=****;password=*******;persist security info=false;Pooling=true;

Comment: You still did not tell use which driver do you use. What is your `OracleConnection` object, i.e. from which name space?

Comment: I use this Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll file and    using (OracleConnection objOracleConnection = new OracleConnection(strOraConnectionString))
             {
                 using (OracleCommand objOracleCommand = new OracleCommand())
                 {

Answer (score 0):

According [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E51173_01/win.122/e17732/featGlobal.htm#ODPNT437) ODP.NET, Managed Driver does not depend on `NLS_LANG` settings, just on .NET locale.

Check your `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` value. This page [How to: Set the Culture and UI Culture for ASP.NET Web Page Globalization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx) should help you. You must set a culture which supports Arabic characters.

Verify again that data type of column `SP_FLG` is `NVARCHAR2`, resp. `NCLOB` (not `VARCHAR2`)

Also try to use bind variables:

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE SHAHR_POS SET SP_FLG = :val"
cmd.Parameters.Add("val", OracleDbType.NVarchar2, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = "سلام"
```

Comment: my dear friend I used that but not work. My Problem remains :(

Comment: thanks  @Wernfried Domscheit  , But My Problem remains :(

Comment: Strange, does it work when you run `UPDATE SHAHR_POS SET SP_FLG = UNISTR('\0633\0644\0627\0645')`?

Comment: thanks for your attention, but this not work. updated my database (sp_flg) whith NULL

Comment: Then I assume you have a problem at your database. Are you really sure data type of column `SP_FLG` is `NVARHCAR2`?

Comment: i changed approach to save utf-8 data to windows 1256 unicode with varchar(). thats not problem with me. it's ok :)