# Problem with accented characters encoding between client and oracle server

Tags: c#, oracle

I've got an oracle database which NLS_CHARACTERSET is AL32UTF8.
I've got an application (ASP.NET C#) on a client which NLS_LANG is FRENCH_FRANCE.WE8MSWIN1252.

The accented characters are well displayed on the application.
However, when there is an accented character in a WHERE clause, oracle doesn't find the data, although it's there.

I found that "é" was written in the database as "c3a9". This is done on the server (SqlDeveloper) so it works fine because there is no conversion yet between character sets.
[image: accented characters preview]

However, in my application on the client, an SQL request with a clause WHERE which contains an accented character doesn't work. For exemple I have this request :

```
string request = "UPDATE fonction SET libelle = '" + new_libelle.Replace("'", "''") + "' WHERE libelle = '" + old_libelle.Replace("'", "''") + "'";
```

If there is an accented character in old_libelle, oracle doesn't find the data and so the update is not executed.

I cannot change the NLS_CHARACTERSET of the database because it's used by many other applications and I don't want side effects to appear.

How to fix this?

Comment: The encoding is correct for UTF8, and your post contains a where clause with accents that works just fine. You'll need to provide more information about what doesn't work.

Comment: @Mat I have edited my post with more information.

Comment: And how is that string getting encoded by your application? Also, use bind variables and prepared statements, manually concatenating strings like that hasn't been a good practice since forever.

Comment: Which driver/provider do you use in your application?

Comment: As @Mat said, use paramters. Example https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/Parameters.html

Comment: How did you set your `NLS_LANG`? In Registry or as environment variable?

Comment: @Mat I don't know exactly.

Comment: @Wernfried Domscheit I'm using msdaora provider.
I didn't set NLS_LANG. But I can see it by using regedit.

Comment: msdaora provider is outdated for ages, you should not use it. It does not support Unicode, however for some french characters it should work.

Comment: @Wernfried Domscheit Haha I'm a junior developer so I did as other applications are done in my company :) What provider can I use instead?

Comment: Check this list for available drivers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34803106/how-to-connect-to-oracle-11-database-from-net/34805999#34805999

Answer (score 0):

Check the encoding settings in your web environment, e.g. `Response.ContentEncoding` and/or `Response.Charset`

If you set `NLS_LANG=FRENCH_FRANCE.WE8MSWIN1252` then you must set these values `Encoding.WindowsCodePage` (which should be CP-1252 in your case)

Otherwise, if you prefer Unicode, (most likely `UTF-8`) then set your `NLS_LANG` accordingly to `FRENCH_FRANCE.AL32UTF8`

Comment: In the web environment, the charset is 'utf-8'.
I don't know how to set NLS_LANG directly in my application, can you explain a little more please?
I can't change the NLS_LANG of the client because there are several other applications runing on it.

Comment: In the command line when you start your application add `SET NLS_LANG=FRENCH_FRANCE.AL32UTF8` at the beginning, then it should be fine. Or use the ODP.NET Managed Driver (`Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client`) which is not `NLS_LANG` sensitive.

Comment: But this is to do every time the application is run isn't it? My application will be used by users that are not used with coding, and it's not convenient for them to run a command line in order to make the application work.

Comment: If you cannot set `NLS_LANG` for entire machine nor for the process then there is no other way than using the ODP.NET Managed Driver.

Comment: I think I'm not far from using this driver. This is what I have :
`conDB = new OracleConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["oraclecs"].ToString());`


`<add name="oraclecs" connectionString="Password=xxxx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxxx;Data Source=xxxx" providerName="msdaora" />`