# Does ASP.NET MVC5 support Oracle 8i

Tags: oracle, asp.net-mvc-5

Sorry if this topics is off, but I try to google it but couldn't find anything. So the problem is following. 
I have to create WEB API (CRUD operation) and my DB is Oracle (`Oracle 8i version`) 
and `.NET framework is 4.6.1`
My question is Does ASP.NET MVC5 support old version of Oracle database or just newest starting from Oracle 10,11,12 ? 
I would be very thankfull If someone can guide me and help me to resolve this problem 
Cheers ! ! !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the main question is about the .NET framework version.

You have to ask: "Does my Data provider supports Oracle 8i"

I am not familiar with ASP.NET, i.e. I don't know which data providers can be used. In general you can use

- ODBC driver
- OLE DB Provider
- Data Provider for .NET

See [How to connect to Oracle 11 database from . net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34803106/how-to-connect-to-oracle-11-database-from-net/34805999#34805999) for more details.

I assume you have to use a Data Provider for .NET. The **Microsoft .NET Framework Data Provider for Oracle** is deprecated for ages, you should not use it. The **Oracle Data Provider for .NET** for .NET framework version 4.x was introduced for Oracle 11.2.

According to [Client / Server Interoperability Support Matrix for Different Oracle Versions (Doc ID 207303.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=207303.1) you can connect to an Oracle 8i database with a Client older than version 10.2.0 (in case "8i" means version "8.1.7").

[image]

So, you have to switch to .NET Framework version 2.x, then you can use the **Oracle Data Provider for .NET** version 10.2 (`2.102.2.20`) which can connect to an Oracle 8.1.7 database.

In case you need a simple and short answer:

No, you cannot connect to an Oracle 8i Database with an application running at .NET framework 4.5.1 - unless you use the deprecated [Microsoft .NET Framework Data Provider for Oracle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/oracle-and-adonet) and an old Oracle 10 client. Note, the Oracle 10 client cannot connect to a Oracle database 12.1.0 or newer.

Comment: I am also not familiar so much with Oracle and .NET. I have never used it before, that's why I ask question like this. Either I dont know what Data Provider to use it. 
However thank you :)

Comment: The link you provided from https://support.oracle.com require registration but registration require "Your Company has a Valid Oracle Support Contract" which is not possible to have for more about 24 year old database.

Comment: @amuliar I put a copy of the matrix