# C# - ODBC Connection fails

Tags: c#, oracle, odbc

I have an problem with an ODBC connection and C# scripting, when opening an ODBC connection.

The error message is: 
Specified driver could not be loaded due to system error  1114: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed. (Oracle in instantclient_12_32bit, C:\Oracle\instantclient_12_32bit\SQORA32.DLL) driver could not be found.

The ORACLE_HOME and Path environment variables are set with correct path "C:\Oracle\instantclient_12_32bit".

Has anyone an idea, what's the problem? The dll is in the directory as named.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you compile your application as 32-bit or 64-bit (or "AnyCPU")?

Comment: What is your connectionString?

Comment: hey, thanks for your fast reply! the driver is configured with the following attributes: dsn = "meddb", tns service name = "ek_nt_ed", userid = "dp" The test for the connection works also. the connection string I am using is the following: connstring = "dsn=meddb;server=ek_nt_ed;uid=dp;pwd=XXX;" Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: maybe also interesting: its configured as system dsn.

Comment: Your connectionString does not specify any driver, it should not work.

Comment: if I am using an connection string like: connstring = "driver={Oracle in instantclient_12_32bit};dsn=meddb;server=ek_nt_ed;uid=dp;pwd=XXX;" with Oracle in instantclient_12_32bit as driver name (from system driver),  I am getting the same error message.. any other idea? :) Thanks!

Comment: You did not answer my first question yet.

Comment: Sorry, the application is compiled as 32bit.

Comment: Then it should work actually. Did you install more then one Oracle Client? Perhaps you messed them up. How do you try to connect, please show us your code. Maybe have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34803106/how-to-connect-to-oracle-11-database-from-net/34805999#34805999