# 'The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle Client'. What do I do? Oracle 19.4.0

Tags: c#, oracle

I've been working on a C# Web Application for a while now, with the purpose of pulling values from a table and displaying them in a list box. However, once I run this program, it throws an exception at Line 37:

```
System.TypeInittalizationException: 'The type initializer for 
'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection' threw an exception.'
Inner Exception
OracleException: The provider is not compatible with the version of
Oracle Client
```

I've been searching for possible solutions across the internet, but they are all pretty outdated and I haven't been able to catch onto any fixes (I am relatively new and inexperienced with Oracle).

Here is the code. Any help would be appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Types;

namespace Employee_Web_3
{
    public partial class FirstWebPage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        int MAX;
        List<string> save_vector = new List<string>();
        List<string> line_vector = new List<string>();
        List<string> singled_vector = new List<string>();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Pull Values
        {
            MAX = int.Parse(Value_Count.Text);
            if (MAX <= 0)
            {
                Failure_Notice.Visible = true;
                Failure_Notice.Text = "Enter in a number greater than 0!";
            }
            else
            {
                string constr = "User Id=USER; Password=PASSWORD; Data Source=ORACLE DATABASE; enlist=false; pooling=false";
                OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(constr); //This is where the exception is being thrown
                conn.Open();

                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
                cmd.Connection = conn;

                string line = MAX.ToString();

                cmd.CommandText = "select (employee_fname || ', ' || employee_lname || ' ' || employee_id) from Employee where employee_id <= " + line;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    E_List.Items.Add(dr.GetString(0));
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < E_List.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    save_vector.Add(E_List.Items[i].ToString());
                    line_vector.Add(E_List.Items[i].ToString());
                }

                conn.Dispose();

                E_List.Visible = true;
                Pull_Values.Visible = false;
                Value_Count.Visible = false;
                Failure_Notice.Visible = false;
                Prompt_.Visible = false;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone is able to give a solution, I would be very thankful

Comment: What is your connection string?  The driver in the connection string is the issue.

Comment: You should write your statement with bind variables.

Answer (score 0):

You code has

```
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Types;
```

The `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` is different to `Oracle.DataAccess`, maybe this one helps: [How to connect to Oracle 11 database from . net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34803106/how-to-connect-to-oracle-11-database-from-net/34805999#34805999)

Usually is does not make sense to use both of then, use only either of them

Looks like you installed several stuff. Check which DLL is actually loaded with:

```
conn.GetType().Assembly.Location
conn.GetType().Assembly.FullName
```

In case of `Oracle.DataAccess` compare it **carefully** with the version of your Oracle Client, the have to match exactly.

Have also a look at this one: [The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659341/the-provider-is-not-compatible-with-the-version-of-oracle-client#25412992)