# The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application QODBC3: Unable to connect"

Tags: c++, oracle, qt, odbc

I'm trying to connect my QT application to the Oracle database I have installed Oracle 11g and Oracle instant client 19.9.
I configured my data source in a way that I believe is correct I added my env variable to the PATH

odbc 32 configuration:
[image: odbc 32 configuration]

and here's my coode function

```
bool db_connection::connect(){
    bool test=false;
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");
    db.setDatabaseName("projetQT");
    db.setUserName("admin");//inserer nom de l'utilisateur
    db.setPassword("****");//inserer mot de passe de cet utilisateur


    if (db.open())
    test=true;

    else
           qDebug()<<db.lastError().text();
           qDebug() << "Connexion FAILED.";
           qDebug() << "Driver disponible: " << db.drivers();
           qDebug() << "Driver fonctionnel(QODBC): " << db.isDriverAvailable("QODBC");
           qDebug() << "database erreur: " << db.lastError().databaseText();
           qDebug() << "driver erreur: " << db.lastError().driverText();
           qDebug() << "type erreur: " << db.lastError().type();



        return  test;
}
```

And I get the error " The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application QODBC3: Unable to connect"
does anyone have a solution for me?

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft ODBC for Oracle driver is [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/odbc-driver-for-oracle?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15) for ages, is does not work anymore with Oracle client 18 or newer.

Use the Oracle ODBC driver, e.g. [Instant Client Downloads for Microsoft Windows (x64) 64-bit](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/winx64-64-downloads.html) or [Instant Client Downloads for Microsoft Windows 32-bit](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/microsoft-windows-32-downloads.html)

[image]

Comment: hat's exactly what I am using , i installed the instant client 19.9 . how do you suggest i implement the code on QT ?

Comment: I am not talking about the Oracle Client, you have to use the ODBC driver from Oracle, not the Microsoft one.  See difference in added screenshot. Maybe this one helps also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34803106/how-to-connect-to-oracle-11-database-from-net/34805999#34805999