# SSIS - Oracle - ODBC driver could not be loaded due to system error code 1114

Tags: oracle, ssis, odbc

I'm trying to connect to Oracle using ODBC Drivers.

As we know Visual studio is a 32bit software.

So I installed Oracle ODBC 32bit drivers ,I tested it ,and its working.
Here is the proof :
[image]

#the problem is:
When it comes to SSIS, the same ODBC configuration that its successful ,now it gives me the following error:
[image]

#what I tried so far:

-I installed Oracle ODBC drivers for 64bit.

-I followed this [tutorial](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/odbc-driver-could-not-be-loaded-due-system-error-code-126-specified-module-could-not-be-found-sqoras32dll-when-trying-manually-create-new-oracle-odbc-system-dsn-caused-missing-32-bit-microsoft-c-library) because they also missing the same dll file ; installing : Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86).

-I even renamed the file with capital letters just like how the error panel is writing it.

-I also installed All Visual-C-Runtimes 32/64 from 2008 to 2017

-And I added the dll file location to the environment variables

-I also done the same thing with my personal laptop and again same error

[image]

[image]

Sadly I still have the same issue.

Comment: Actually your picture is no proof - we don't know whether it shows the 32-bit or the 64-bit ODBC Data Source Administrator. The Datasource name is just free text. Yes, Installing 32-bit and 64-bit Oracle is a bit tricky, follow this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104210/badimageformatexception-this-will-occur-when-running-in-64-bit-mode-with-the-32#24120100 Yes, Visual Studio itself is 32-bit but you can run/debug your application in 32-bit or 64-bit. Again the picture does not show which one you use.

Comment: thank you for your time I do really appreciate it, But as you see I repeated the same thing again ,and I made sure its a 32-bit ODBC (please see 3rd picture I added). but still the same error.

Comment: Probably missing entry in system path.   See demonstration [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/232052/oracle-odbc-connection-failure-using-oracles-stock-odbc-drivers).

Comment: Can you connect with ODBC when you try manually by code? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34803106/how-to-connect-to-oracle-11-database-from-net/34805999#34805999 Use the [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to see which are actually loaded and where it fails to load them.

Comment: @vhoang thank you sooo much , i followed the demonstration you provided me ,and its working fine. how can i mark you answer as the solution ??

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit NIIIICE finally i found a way to debug with :D , I'm glad that you shared it with me , thank you soo much.

Comment: @ConsolDotLog, glad it worked out for you.  It was an initial guess that didn't have a great certainty of working.   I've reposted the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This 1114 error can show up with Oracle Instant Client when the PATH variable is not set to where the dll can be found.

It's unusual because it connects okay through the ODBC DSN setup tool but not SSDT (VS).

Primary Solution:

- Update the PATH in System Variables to include the location of instant client and restart SSDT.