# Connect c# Visual Studio 2019 to Oracle Database 19c

Tags: c#, database, oracle, visual-studio, connection

I installed Oracle 19c on a pc, then installed the ODT driver. In the server browser, I chose to connect to Oracle Database and after I don't understand how to connect the database, in all videos and guides, Data source name is selected from the drop-down menu, but for me it is empty. Oracle is installed.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIkgg.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJjX5.png)

Comment: Maybe this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34803106/how-to-connect-to-oracle-11-database-from-net/34805999#34805999

Comment: You installed the Oracle database server, but did you also create a database and did you start it?