# Oracle client and network components were not found

Tags: oracle, visual-studio

I start with VS2019 and oracle, and I try to connect my app to a oracle, but I have this message.

> Oracle client and networking components were not found. These components are supplied by Oracle Corporation and are part of the Oracle Version on 7.3.3 or later client software installation.

My PC is 64 bit, but visual studio and oracle client are 32 bit, at compilation preferences destiny cpu value is X86.

I install oracle at C:\oracle\client_1 and the environment variable path includes C:\oracle\client_1\bin

¿Any ideas?

thanks

Comment: Which provider/driver do you try to use?

Comment: Which client version did you install? The old, deprecated MS drivers do not work anymore with Oracle Client 18 or newer, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34803106/how-to-connect-to-oracle-11-database-from-net/34805999#34805999

Comment: It´s a problem from my personal computer, cause in computer`s job works fine. I use OleDbConnection provider, i have installed oracle 19c

Comment: Then most likely you did not install then OleDb provider. It is not included in the Oracle Instant Client.