# How to Know the Oracle client my .Net application is pointing?

Tags: .net, oracle

Recently Oracle client has been upgraded to 19 from 11 on server. After that my application stopped working.
I replicated the same issue on my local machine after installing Oracle 19 and now I have 2 Oracle instances on my machine while server has just 1(Oracle 19).

Is there any way to know which Oracle client version my .Net application is pointing to?

Comment: Try `connection.GetType().Assembly.Location` Maybe you use an outdated Namespace, some do not work anymore with Oracle 19 client, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34803106/how-to-connect-to-oracle-11-database-from-net/34805999#34805999

Comment: If you don't get it from code, then use [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon)