# Can’t get references to update from OracleClient to ManagedDataAccess in .Net Web Applicaiton

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, visual-studio

I had to take over and existing .Net WebForms project that was built a long time ago. It was using an old OracleClient that I’m pretty sure was 32bit. I’m now having to move it off a Windows 2008 server and put it on a newer server that I believe only has the 64bit Oracle client installed. I’ve been struggling to get it to communicate with Oracle so we decided to try to install the latest version of OracleManagedData driver to the Project in Visual Studio through NuGet.

The original developer used some sort of GUI, I’m assuming inside Visual Studio, to create an .xsd file for the database. When I do a search for OracleClient it finds references in the DataSet.Designer.cs file that is part of the .xsd file. When a build on the project I get a bunch of warnings that the OracleDataAdapter is obsolete. I then tried manually updating the `private global::System.Data.OracleClient.OracleDataAdapter _adapter;` over to `private global::Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataAdapter _adapter;` and of course that threw about 1,700 errors because I need to update all of the Adapters, Connections, and Commands from `System.Data.OracleClient` to `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess`.
How can I get everything to get converted over to the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess properly? I did some searching and found where I can open the DataSet.xsd file with DataSet Editor in Visual Studio but I have no idea how or if I can use that to switch over to the ManageDataAccess.

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated. I have limited knowledge working with Oracle.

Comment: What do you mean by "it was using an old OracleClient"? Maybe check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34803106/how-to-connect-to-oracle-11-database-from-net/34805999#34805999 Some methods are are the same in `System.Data.OracleClient` and `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client`, i.e. you can just update the reference. But you may have to re-write some code.

Comment: `System.Data.OracleClient` is deprecated and available only for 32-bit. However, the more modern providers/drives are available for 32-bit and 64-bit. It's up to you which one you like to use. The `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` does not require any Oracle Client installation. You can install 32-bit **and** 64-bit Oracle client on one machine.

Answer (score -1):

Well, it is VERY but beyond VERY doubt full that the type of provider was changed.

So, sure, remove the older provider references in the project, use nuget to add the newer and later provider.

Now, check your settings - see if a general connection setting was used, right?

Project-> near last selection "my project name" properties.

You get this:

[image]

If they used above, then that connection string setting is then pushed out to web.config. So, if you don't see your connection in above, then check web config.

So, you can even use the conneciton builder for above - right?
(I mean, how else could and would and did you setup a conneciton in the past, right????).

Ok, now either above, or web.config will have your conneciton string.

I would FOR SURE anyway add a working connection using the above settings - since then you get the new connection builder - and it has a test connection, right? So, at least you now have a known and working valid connection. I mean, even add a new connection (so 20 seconds of your time to add a new connection to above settings).

At this point?

Open up the data set designer for the given data model. You might have one, or several. Remember, the older dataset designer is VERY much like EF now (entity framework).

In fact, open up the code generated by that desinger.

So, if you dataset is called mydb, or say TEST3 or whatever?

The open up the "DESINGER NAME".Designer.cs

in side, you find the connection string being used.

Say like this:

```
    private void InitConnection() {
        this._connection = new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
        this._connection.ConnectionString = g 
        lobal::CSharpWebApp.Properties.Settings.Default.TEST3;
    }
```

So, the above will be taken from the first screen cap - your applcation settings. Those settings actually make their way into web.config.

So, really, you simple want to modify the SAME connection setting having been used before. In above, my setting was test3. In fact, you can by pass both the "settings" page, by-pass the dataset desinger, and jump right into web config, and modify the "test3" connection string.

Say, I wanted to point now to production server, or say some other database?

Then just change that connection string.

So, you removed the references to the older oracle data provider? Right?

eg;

[image]

Then you used nuget to add the newer later version.

Then you updated your connection strings
(in web config).

you should be quite much done at this point in time.

As for the dataset designer? Yes, you should be able to just click on it, and open it, and the dataset designer should launch - it VERY similar to Entity frame work.

You don't edit or modify that xsd file yourself - it like a web form, or just about anything else - you use the designers in VS to do this.

So, fi you open up the xsd file? You should see the data designer launch, say like this:

[image]

So, when I open a xsd file, I see the the above. It is a data model desinger, and as noted, you can think of that data set designer like "v1" of  what most use now (Entitify frame work).

That designer just abstracts out the database to a set of data objects.

As noted, the above dataset designer? Close it, and check our the above "myname.desinger.cs" file that it generated - the connection string used should be defined. Now, just go edit the connection string - and that dataset designer should now be using your newer connection, and also should for the most part use the newer data provider you added via nuget.

So, how both desktop applications, and even web based systems? They both typical used the dataset designer, and how this works is standard fair. As noted, the dataset designer is similar to EF used today.

I have often lamented that the connection string can't be changed in the dataset designer - but then again, probably a good thing you can't SINCE then the developer was FORCED to use a single common connection string, and that fact going to be MUCH TO your advantage here, since to get the basic data modes and data interaction this web site uses will VERY likely mean you can and should be able to JUST change the connection string, and update to the newer oracle provider, and you back in business.

However, oracle is quite good - and I doubt they deprecated the older data provider - and it probably would still even work - you just have to change the connection string - and that would have been the first thing to try.

It is not all that clear as to why the older oracle data provider does not work - I believe they still do. But, as noted, sure, and yes, I would update the older data provider. However, such a upgrade likely would not break the applcation.

Comment: Namespace `System.Data.SqlClient` is used to connect to an Microsoft SQL Server, not Oracle database.

Comment: Thanks for all the info. It at least gives me some things to look at. I'll come back and let everyone know if I get it working or if I'm still struggling with it. I will say that even with Entity Framework, I use the design from database feature and not the GUI so I've never really used that database designer before.