# How to connect Oracle EBS remote database using ODBC driver?

Tags: odbc, oracle-ebs

I am not sure how I can connect my Oracle EBS remote database through ODBC driver. From which ODBC driver we can connect my Oracle EBS remote database? Also, what configuration does it need?

I tried to use Oracle Instant Client ODBC driver, but It is not working.

Comment: What means "not working"? There are several ODBC drivers available for Oracle, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34803106/how-to-connect-to-oracle-11-database-from-net/34805999#34805999 Most important is, that the architecture (i.e. 32-bit / 64-bit) of the ODBC driver matches the architecture of your application.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle EBS is configured by default with IP restrictions - this means that only "trusted nodes" are allowed to connect to the DB (these are listed in [tusted.conf](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26401_01/doc.122/e22952/T156458T659600.htm)).

You can add Admin nodes via an autoconfig variable.  See the [EBS Security Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26401_01/doc.122/e22952.pdf) (Protecting Administrative Pages) and the Autoconfig documentation (Document 387859.1, Using AutoConfig to Manage System Configurations with Oracle Applications Release 12) for more information on how to do this.  If this is a production instance, your organization should have strict controls on who can be trusted.