# How to Identify which version of Oracle dll we are using in .Net Application

Tags: .net, oracle, oracle11g, oracle19c

We have a legacy application with the .Net version of 3.5.
we are using oracle 11g for that application when we tried to update the database version to 19c the application was not compatible.

Now I want to check where in application I can update the oracle dll version and make it compatible with oracle 19c

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too broad, you can use many drivers, see [How to connect to Oracle 11 database from . net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34803106/how-to-connect-to-oracle-11-database-from-net/34805999#34805999)

In general you can find the loaded DLL with this command:

```
connection.GetType().Assembly.Location
```

In case "11g" means version 11.2, then it should work.
See [Client / Server Interoperability Support Matrix for Different Oracle Versions (Doc ID 207303.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=207303.1)

[image]

[image]

Be aware, in case of "*Oracle Data Provide for .NET*" the version of DLL must match **exactly** the version of installed Oracle Client.