# Azure Function (.NET 6) connect to on-prem Oracle 8i database

Tags: .net, oracle, azure-functions

I am trying to move an integration to the cloud using Function Apps (.NET 6) connecting to a very old on-prem Oracle 8i database.  I have spent a few days trying different Nuget packages and different connection strings but I can't connect.  I have tried Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core, System.Data.OracleClient (this throws a unable to load oci dll error and is deprecated anyway) and a few others in the Nuget store.

I can see the connections coming through the firewall (Function App has VNET integration going through ExpressRoute) but using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core and a connection string of "**Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=myHost)(PORT=myPort))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=mySIDId)));User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword**" i get the following on OracleConnection.Open()

**Index was outside the bounds of the array**

*at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.PoolManager`3.CreateNewPR(Int32 reqCount, Boolean bForPoolPopulation, ConnectionString csWithDiffOrNewPwd, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria, Boolean bMaxSemObtained, Boolean bIgnoreIdleSem, Boolean& bIdleSemObtainedWhileCreatingPR, String instanceName, List`1 switchFailedInstNames)
at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OraclePoolManager.CreateNewPR(Int32 reqCount, Boolean bForPoolPopulation, ConnectionString csWithDiffOrNewPwd, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria, Boolean bMaxSemObtained, Boolean bIgnoreIdleSem, Boolean& bIdleSemObtainedWhileCreatingPR, String instanceName, List`1 switchFailedInstNames) at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.PoolManager`3.Get(ConnectionString csWithDiffOrNewPwd, Boolean bGetForApp, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch)
at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OraclePoolManager.Get(ConnectionString csWithNewPassword, Boolean bGetForApp, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch)
at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OracleConnectionDispenser`3.Get(ConnectionString cs, PM conPM, ConnectionString pmCS, SecureString securedPassword, SecureString securedProxyPassword, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria)
at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()*

It is obviously an issue in PoolManager.CreateNewPR() method (and i can't seem to debug it by adding new "function" breakpoint) but I don't know what the issue is and whether it is the version of Oracle being connected to on-prem and whether Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core supports this or not.  As mentioned I have tried the oldest version of this nuget package and a bunch of other Oracle based ones (official, unofficial, deprecated), nothing seems to work.

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Client / Server Interoperability Support Matrix for Different Oracle Versions](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=207303.1) to see which Oracle client is needed.

[image]

Looks like, you need to install a 10.2.0 Oracle client (in case 8i means version 8.1.7)

Note, the version of ODP.NET provider (`Oracle.DataAccess.dll`) must match the version of the Oracle client **exactly**. It would be either  "Oracle Data Provider for .NET 1.x 10.2.0.2.20" or "Oracle Data Provider for .NET 2.0 10.2.0.2.20"

These are based on .NET version 1 and 2, I don't think they work with .NET version 6. And they are available only for 32bit (x86), of course.

But instead of using the Oracle ODP.NET you could use the old Microsoft ODBC or OleDB provider, they certainly work with the old client.

See also [How to connect to Oracle 11 database from . net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34803106/how-to-connect-to-oracle-11-database-from-net/34805999#34805999)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I will look into this.  One question though, if I need to use old ODBC or OLEDB won't that need an oracle client install on the machine the app is running?

Comment: Yes, every driver/provider needs to have an Oracle client installed, they all use the `oci.dll`. Only the ODP.NET Managed Drivers (`Oracle.ManagedDataAccess`) are stand-alone driver which do not have any dependencies. But there the lowest version is 12.1 which does not work with an Oracle 8i database.