System.Data.OracleClient DLL is actually working with oracle client 19c. How is it possible?
I had searched for this specific question and have not found a single clue about why this happens.
I am migrating some old ASP.NET websites to an IIS on a newer server that uses System.Data.OracleClient DLL which is obsolete. From what I've gathered, this wasn't suppose to work with ODAC 19.21, but somehow the websites are working fine in the new server.
Anyone can enlighten me why this happens? This is actually a good thing because it will mean less effort, but I am totally curious of why is this happening.
I had configured the ASP.NET and ODP.NET on the machine and added both ASP.NET (Oracle.Web) and ODP.NET (Oracle.DataAccess) to the GAC, in case this info helps.

People often call that "luck", as even deprecated things might work sometimes (too many examples). But no one should expect that luck can last very long.

Yes, it is deprecated but is still works. However, "Microsoft ODBC for Oracle" and "MSDAORA" will fail, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34803106/how-to-connect-to-oracle-11-database-from-net/34805999#34805999
