With Windows 11 upgrade, VBA Microsoft Excel add-in tool is not connecting to the 10g Oracle database any longer using MSDAORA
With Windows 11 upgrade, VBA Microsoft Excel add-in tool is not connecting to the 10g Oracle database any longer using MSDAORA.
What we have - Oracle 10g Database, 10g Oracle Client
What are we doing - Trying to connect to an Oracle 10g database with a Microsoft Excel VBA add-in tool and cannot connect using MSDAORA.
Our current connection string -
"Provider=MSDAORA;Data Source=" & gstrDATABASE & ";User ID=" & strUserID & ";Password=" & strPassword
We know we need a new provider but we cannot upgrade the database, we are stuck at 10g for the forseeable future. What are our options?

Needs more detail - for example what is the actual error message you're getting?  Did you move from 32-bit to 64-bit office when you upgraded to Win 11?

Yes we moved from 32-bit to 64-bit when we upgraded and the actual error message is - "Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed."

MSDAORA works only with 32-bit. You need to install 32-bit Excel and 32-bit Oracle client. But you can easily switch to 64-bit by using a different provider, just change the connection string accordingly. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34803106/how-to-connect-to-oracle-11-database-from-net/34805999#34805999

Wouldn't we need to install a new client? We are using a 10g client for a 10g database and using MSDAORA, would this be a case of installing ODAC and using say, 12g client (which we have already installed, just not pointed to) and ORAOLE.db as the provider?

12g client can connect to a 10g database - backwards compatibility is pretty well maintained given how many folks are stuck with various older DB server versions..

Do we also need ODAC installed?

According to Client / Server Interoperability Support Matrix for Different Oracle Versions you need to install an Oracle Client not newer than 12.1 - if "10g" means 10.2, otherwise not newer than 11.1

As pointed in my comment, if your Excel is 64-bit, then the Oracle client (and drivers) must be also 64-bit. If you stay on 32-bit Excel, then Oracle must be 32-bit accordingly.
The MSDAORA driver works only with 32-bit. If you run 64-bit, then you must use another provider, I would suggest to use the "Oracle Provider for OLE DB", it should be the most seamless migration. You need to adapt your connection string, and install the "Oracle Provider for OLE DB", it is part of the Oracle ODAC package. Oracle ODBC Driver would be another option.

I cannot access the link to see the matrix but judging by the snip you have posted above it would appear like nothing is compatible anymore with 10.2 or 10.1, right? Each row says either "No" or "Was". I cannot find any downloads for any 10x clients and we have an 11g64 client but not sure if we configured it correctly. With the 11g64 I am able to connect to the DB with SQL Plus but when we try to connect through Excel and VBA we get a provider not found error. VBA version we are running is 7.1 in a 64 bit Excel on Windows 11.
